# Отслеживать состояние шары

Tags: c#, .net, windows

Имеется некоторый сетевой ресурс и нужно, если он стал недоступен что-то сделать.

На сколько правильно использовать FileSystemWatcher и какие возможны подводные камни?

В этот объект я передаю путь к сетевой шаре, отслеживаю переименовывание(Как я понял в моем случае пофиг что отслеживать), а подписываюсь на событие Error.

Как можно узнать, что шара стала снова доступна?

Comment: меня вероятно будут бить, но почему бы просто не пытаться периодически по таймеру отправлять на шару пустой текстовый файл? так сразу и доступность и наличие прав проверить можно, и трафика считай что нет.

Comment: `FileSystemWatcher`  можно использовать (главное не напороться с проблемами безопасности).   
А еще лучше, предварительно примонтировать папку к диску используя `NET USE` задав сразу пользователя и пароль, если надо, и вотчить уже этот диск